AgGrid: Expand / Collapse Groups via API (Streamlit)
there is doc JavaScript Grid: Row Grouping - Opening Groups  how to call AgGrid api and expand or collapse groups by clicking the button in streamlit framework?
Can you help me to implement the same functionality with streamlit and using python?
I tried to use JsCode from aggrid package but it supports through parameters and not as external button.
I found "groupDefaultExpanded" option for configure_grid_options that controls the number of levels to expand.
gb.configure_grid_options(groupDefaultExpanded=levels)

as workaround I set up the value of "levels" to maximum possible and can change to 0 if I want to collapse rows.
